# ARPACK no longer works on M2 Mac (OS 13.5)

Tags: python, macos, scipy, eigenvalue

My question is how to update Python code that uses scipy's ARPACK routines to compute eigenvalues so that it runs with the current version of scipy. I think, if I understood correctly, that computation of eigenvalues in scipy has changed and that this requires a different way of calling these routines.

Warning: my questions may not be posed correctly. I am using and editing code that a colleague previously wrote, and I am barely a beginner in python coding.

I have a set of python data analysis routines (written by a colleague who is no longer available) that run fine on an Intel Mac running Monterey (Mac OS 12), running Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda Navigator. I am trying to run the same routines on an M2 Macbook Air runnning Ventura (OS 13.5.2). I installed the current (December 2023) version of Anaconda Navigator to run Python via Jupyter Notebook. When execution hits the line:

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack import eigsh as largest_eigsh
```

I get the error message:

```
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 from scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack import eigsh as largest_eigsh
      3 #from scipy.linalg import eigh as largest_eigh
      5 from project_fog.settings import DetectorModule

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack'; 'scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen' is not a package
```

A sample line of code that uses eigenvalue computations is:

```
            _, ua_i = largest_eigsh(Ga_new, 1, which='LM')
```

I looked at the following webpage on scipy's documentation website, but even after reading this I am not sure how to rewrite the line:

from scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack import eigsh as largest_eigsh

into an updated form that is acceptable to scipy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the commented-out line below it, `from scipy.linalg import eigh as largest_eigh`? That looks like it should do the same job. It will return an eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector. See the documentation for eight: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.

Comment: The change is probably not due to the machine but the version of SciPy. Try `import scipy; scipy.__version__` on each machine. `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack` was not publicly documented, so it was considered private. Private code can change without notice, so it is best to use a public function like `eigh`.